# What's the difference between these two assumptions?

Tags: complex-analysis

I see that the Cauchy Integral Formula follows from the Cauchy-Green Formula (both stated below), but I am unsure what the difference is in their assumptions.

$\underline{Cauchy-Green \, Formula:}$
Suppose $D$ is a bounded domain with piecewise smooth boundary.  If $g(z)$ is a smooth complex-valued function on $D \cup \partial D$, then
$$ g(w) = \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{\partial D} \frac{g(z)}{z - w}dz - \frac{1}{\pi} \iint_D \frac{\partial g}{\partial \overline{z}} \frac{1}{z - w}dxdy $$
for all $w \in D$.

$\underline{Cauchy \, Integral \, Formula:}$
Suppose $D$ is a bounded domain with piecewise smooth boundary.  If $f(z)$ is analytic on $D$ and $f(z)$ extends smoothly to the boundary of $D$, then
$$ f(z) = \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{\partial D} \frac{f(w)}{w - z}dw $$
for all $z \in D$.

From what I understand, 'analytic' means 'having a power series expansion'.  Doesn't this mean that an analytic function is smooth?  Cauchy's theorem must be assuming something stronger in order to drop the double integral from the formula, but I don't see what the difference is.

Comment: Cauchy Riemann equations say that analyticity of $g$ is the same as $\frac{\partial g}{\partial \bar{z}} = 0$.

Comment: Analytic implies smooth, but not vice versa. An analytic (or holomorphic) function $g$ satisfies $\frac{\partial g}{\partial \overline{z}} = 0$.